# Keep connection when using ChromeDriver in websites which require authentication

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using VBA and Selenium ChromeDriver for data scraping in a website which requires authentication.

The problem is, ChromerDriver seems to restart in any interruption in the code (even if it is not an error, for instance when the application asks the user for input).

```
' Loads search page
Set chrome = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

Do
    chrome.get sfSearchURL

    If chrome.URL <> sfSearchURL Then 'If it is not in desired search page, prompts user to log in.
        intCont = MsgBox ("Log in and click OK")

        If intCont = vbCancel Then
            strErrorMsg = "Not logged in"
            Exit Function
        End If

    End If

Loop Until chrome.URL = sfSearchURL
```

When I load the search page without being logged in, the server loads the login page instead.

The problems are:

**First**, each time I open ChromeDriver, it opens a new session and forgets the authentication, so I can't have a session, having to log in again in each execution of the search function.

**Second**, when VBA shows the MsgBox and user clicks OK, variable `chrome` looses the link to the object, and in the next line (`Loop Until`) I get

> runtime error 0: WebRequestError Impossible to connect to remote server

Comment: `intCont = MsgBox (Log in and click OK")` shouldn't compile.  Is `chrome` declared locally, so if `intCont = vbCancel`, does `chrome` drop out of scope when the function is exited? Although, that's never going to be a probablem because there is no way `intCont` can ever equal `vbCancel` in your code.  But as for your problem?  Dunno, couldn't get that far.

Comment: Sorry, I simplified ```MsgBox``` statement in this question for better readability, and forgot the first double quotes, but they are in my code. About the scope, you gave me a insight: making the driver a variable with wider scope should be a useful turnaround (but it would be better being able to open chrome without dropping the authentication). About the ```vbCancel```, in my code the ```MsgBox``` statement is ```vbOKCancel + vbCritical```, so when user cancels it evaluates as intended, exiting the function. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge of HTTP is decidedly weak so I may not be entirely accurate, but I think I'm close enough to get you moving.

Move this outside your loop:

```
chrome.get sfSearchURL
```

What I suspect is happening, is you make a request for a new session with `Get`.  Selenium has an implicit wait with `Get` so the session is created and the URL for that session doesn't match the URL used as the exit condition.  As your code loops back, it calls `Get` again which drops your session for the new request.

This would also cause the branching to MsgBox, notably, it would drop the session before it branches.

---

I have to ask about this though...

> "each time I open ChromeDriver, it opens a new session and forgets the authentication, so I can't have a session, having to log in again in each execution of the search function"
>
> - What **exactly** do you mean by "open ChromeDriver", and how **exactly** are you opening it?

This line:

```
Set chrome = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
```

...is guaranteed to drop whatever session was previously held in `chrome` and open a new session.  This is by design and is exactly what it should do and what you should expect.

If this is part of a larger loop then that's a smoking gun right there.

It is possible to create new sessions from one instance of `chrome` but I use a custom class with different interfaces to initialize separate simultaneous sessions because it makes my project more manageable and consistent.

Also.  You really need to include more if your code for us to help you at our best.  I have to infer and guess my way around what may or may not have been written.